# how to mention ubuntu patch version in dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-pull

is it possible to mention ubuntu patch version in dockerfile
e.g. generally to get ubuntu 16.04 we would have following line in the dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
```

What I want to do is within 16.04 also there will be patch versions like `16.04.04` and `16.04.05` so I want to mention that patch version in the dockerfile.

Is it possible somehow ? It doesn't work if I write `FROM ubuntu:16.04.04`  is there any other syntax ? other way to specify to it.

Answer (score 1):

Those FROM values correspond to literal tag values in the `ubuntu` dockerhub repository.  Whether it is found depends on how the `ubuntu` team tags their docker images and how long they keep older versions.

You can look here to see if one meets your requirements:

https://hub.docker.com/r/library/ubuntu/tags/

It doesn't look like they tag the patch version numbers but they do retain tag patch dates like `xenial-20180228`.  If you know the patch date for 16.04.04, you can look in the tag list in dockerhub and see if one matches or is close.